# Added DFSR to Domain controller, non domain admins can not create shares

Tags: active-directory, dfs-r, windows-server-core, windows-server-2019, namespaces

My situation is I deployed a couple of domain controllers at some locations. My boss didn't want to spend money on servers, so I reused some servers we were not using.

I installed them as domain controllers and added DFSR replication to them.  Everything is working fine, I am having no problems at all, it has been working great for a year or more.

I am working on securing our AD and I am not using my domain admin credentials for anything anymore, just emergencies.

I noticed the other day I can not add new folders and share to the servers that are domain controllers and I understand why I can not. I added my `dfsradmin` AD group to delegation but that did not take care of it. I am just try to work with what I have.

What would be the simplest way to allow a non domain admin to add folders and share them from this server that is a domain controller?

I know it would be best to separate them, but I can't at this point. All of the folders and shares are on a separate volume. This is also Server Core 2019.

Any suggestions?

Worst case scenario is we just add another server to each location with this setup, but I am seeing if I can work with what I have until we can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So after more research I figured out that I should have made these read only domain controllers.  I’m just going to demote them and then add them back as rodc.